# How to use Exclusions in ContourPlot?

Tags: plotting

I want to achieve this effect:
[image]

then, I try the following code:

```
p = ContourPlot[(x - 2)^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, 1, 3}, {y, -1, 1}, 
Axes -> True, Frame -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
Exclusions -> {x <= 2 || y <= 0}, ExclusionsStyle -> Dashed]
```

however, it didn't work. How to do?

Comment: That means you don't want to exclude the dashed line? Try `RegionFunction`instead of `Exclusions`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `RegionFunction` instead of `Exclusions`:

```
p1 = ContourPlot[(x - 2)^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, 1, 3}, {y, -1, 1}, RegionFunction ->  (#2 <= 0 || #1 <= 2 &) , ContourStyle -> Dashed];
p2 = ContourPlot[(x - 2)^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, 1, 3}, {y, -1, 1},RegionFunction ->   (#2 > 0 && 2 <= #1 <= 3 &) ,ContourStyle -> Blue];
Show[{p1, p2}, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]